# Why is Eclipse launch sluggish after Worklight 6.1.0.01 upgrade?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I upgraded Worklight 6.1 to 6.1.0.01 using the "Check for updates" feature of Eclipse.  I chose to install four components:

1. IBM Dojo Mobile Tools
2. IBM jQuery Mobile Tools
3. IBM Worklight Studio
4. IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight

The install proceeded normally. At the end, I received a message indicating that Eclipse needed to be relaunched.  The relaunch took about half an hour, and each time I re-started Eclipse, it also took about half an hour to startup.  Finally I reverted to a previous Eclipse build with Worklight 6.1.

Why is Eclipse launch so sluggish?

Answer (score 0):

**~30 minutes**? every time? that sounds highly abnormal and I have never experienced such a slow start-up of Eclipse (4.2.2 "Juno" SR2 or 4.3.1 "Kepler" SR1 -- the only two supported versions of Eclipse) in Windows or Mac with Worklight. Something's very wrong with your copy of Eclipse IMO...

Try with a fresh copy of Eclipse and/or fresh workspace and see if it continues.

Comment: It's not my day:  

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/wdeupdate/plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_6.1.0.01-20140427-1450.jar.
Read timed out

Comment: That happens sometimes, try again later.